# python:initializing list of sets within dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I want to initialize a list of set to a dictionary.I can directly enter the variables but couldn't initialize it and get input from user.My data structure should look something like this

```
d={1:[{1,2},{3,4}],2:[{2,3},{4,5,100}]}
```

So that,if i want to access the element 100 it could be done as `d[2][1][2]`
.I could define the data structure but couldn't initialize it.Could someone help me to initialize the structure.

Comment: I don't get the problem

Comment: I want to initialize something that could store d.

Comment: d={1:[(1,2),(3,4)],2:[(2,3),(4,5,5)]}, but 1 will be accessed as d[1][0][0]. Beware of zero-based indexing.

Comment: set don't have order, so you can't access a element by position, change that to a tuple or list so you can do that, like _W55tKQbuRu28Q4xv_ show you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to initialise the array of sets automatically. Default dict seems the most appropriate way to do this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(lambda: [set(), set()])
a[100][2].add(2)
print(a.items())
```

This would initialise a list with two sets whenever accessing a non existing key.